# styling form based on other server added to my site by JS

Tags: css, wordpress

i'm trying so much to styling this form based in this page :
http://student.ly/form/
first of all this form added to my site by javascript code only and it's linked to another website..
i mean i can't access the actual code for the form, i want to styling it 
i try doing this :

```
.page-id-1418 .inq
```

and this

```
.page-id-1418 .entry_content input.inq
```

and a lot of other codes no one works to me 
and in the other hand 
this code works fine

```
    .page-id-1418 .post-content iframe{
height:700px !important;
}
```

i want to styling the inputs , any help please?

Answer (score -1):

Try

CSS

```
input.inq {
width:200px;
...
...
}
```